# How to determine if all values equal a certain statement

Tags: json, jira

I am trying to find a way to determine if certain values equal certain statements. I essentially need to state:

```
If {issue.effort level} = "Easier" && {issue.occurence level} = "weekly" && {issue.impact level} = "Excellent"
then
{issue.priority level} = 729
End
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I'd look into ScriptRunner scripted fields for a start